# Wordpress "Show Comments" button not working

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

When editing a post - the "Show Comments" button in the backend wordpress content editor is not working. It is showing a "spinner" as if it is loading, but when clicking on "show comments" nothing happens?

1. I have updated to the latest version of Wordpress
2. I have updated all plugins

Please assist in what else can cause this error?

- Comments can be added and edited in the "comments" section, but not in the edit page or edit post sections

thank you

[image: Screenshot of Error]

Comment: Using Chrome, please press CTRL + SHIFT + J and copy and paste any error you see there?

Comment: @NickDuncan This is what comes up - no errors I don't think?
load-scripts.php:9 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1

Comment: Yup, no errors. How many comments have you got on your site? If there are a large amount of comments the script may be timing out.

Comment: Thank you @NickDuncan I have a total of 105 comments on the site altogether?

Comment: OK, Let's try this: Press CTRL + SHIFT + J, then click on the "Network" tab. Then click on "XHR" and click on the "Show comments" link again. You should see an `admin-ajax.php` line show up. Click on that, then click on the `preview` tab to the right. What does it say in there?

Comment: @NickDuncan  {heartbeat_interval: "standard", wp-auth-check: true, server_time: 1488185198}
heartbeat_interval
:
"standard"
server_time
:
1488185198
wp-auth-check
:
true

Comment: That's the WP heartbeat ajax call which is not applicable in this instance. Was there no other line that popped up when you clicked that link again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136731/discussion-between-nick-duncan-and-user1426583).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that there may be a comment with content (perhaps malicious) that may be breaking the return of all the comments. Try log in to PHPMyAdmin and manually remove suspicious comments from the comments tabe.