# comments box don't show on post edit panel - wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, comments

I have enabled the comments and done all necessary changes, still the comments don't show on post edit page. Although, I can see them on Comments section and also on the page's user side.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFtPK.png)

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42480490/wordpress-show-comments-button-not-working) and didn't find the answer. My site is offline now and working on localhost, so I don't receive any comments. Having said that, the large number of comments is not my problem.

**UPDATE**:
I noticed [this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bs23b.png) on QueryMonitor. Does this mean anything?

**UPDATE2** : I receive different error each time: [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TICn.png)

Comment: Please add the console logs errore

Comment: DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for http://127.0.0.1/yadwood/wp-content/themes/sahar-shop/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for http://127.0.0.1/yadwood/wp-content/themes/sahar-shop/assets/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Comment: There is a console log with a 403 error in the console log. Open the network tab and share the related request.

Comment: @MohammadZarei; I don't receive that error anymore, instead appears a bunch of Deprecated messages, with the title of **PHP Errors in Ajax Response**. I'm totally puzzled.
first I thought that Woocommerce may have conflict with WP, and deactivated it, but the errors are still there